# Как считывать видео поток в вебкамеры, используя только стандартные инструменты в unix?

Tags: c, unix, web-camera

Нужно считывать видеопоток с вебкамеры, без использования opencv. Используя только си и инструменты предоставляемые unix. Я нашел код, который собирает необходимую информацию об устройстве, но я не могу понять, как заставить работать веб камеру, чтоб она начала писать поток.

ВОт код

```
int main (int argc,char* argv[])
{

/*Read Params*/
char *device_name;
if(argc > 1)
{
  device_name = argv[1];
}
else
{
  device_name = "/dev/video0";
}

/*Open Device*/
int  file_device = open(device_name, O_RDWR, 0);

if (file_device == -1)
{
  printf ("%s error %d, %s\n",device_name, errno, strerror(errno));
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

/*Read Params From Device*/
struct v4l2_capability device_params;

if (ioctl(file_device, VIDIOC_QUERYCAP, &device_params) == -1)
{
  printf ("\"VIDIOC_QUERYCAP\" error %d, %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

printf("driver : %s\n",device_params.driver);
printf("card : %s\n",device_params.card);
printf("bus_info : %s\n",device_params.bus_info);
printf("version : %d.%d.%d\n",
     ((device_params.version >> 16) & 0xFF),
     ((device_params.version >> 8) & 0xFF),
     (device_params.version & 0xFF));
printf("capabilities: 0x%08x\n", device_params.capabilities);
printf("device capabilities: 0x%08x\n", device_params.device_caps);

/* Close Device */
if (-1 == close (file_device))
{
  printf ("\"close\" error %d, %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

file_device = -1;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: [здесь](https://linuxtv.org/downloads/v4l-dvb-apis/uapi/v4l/capture.c.html) хороший пример, который демонстрирует все варианты чтения: и с обычным `read`'ом и с `mmap`'ом... ЗЫ: забыл добавить в прошлый раз, что, хотя чтение обычным `read`'ом и возможно, рекомендуется всё же пользоваться `mmap`'ом или тем странным вариантом с `V4L2_MEMORY_USERPTR`... ЗЗЫ: если этого недостаточно, то могу попробовать завтра набросать какой-нить примерчик попроще... ЗЗЗЫ: и да, v4l, как говорит название, есть только под Linux, на других ОС интерфейсы будут сильно отличаться...

Comment: @Fat-Zer, v4l программа должна в общем уметь и mmap и userptr и dma, так как разные камеры могут работать только по одному из этих способов, ну и бывают ещё камеры несовместимые с v4l2

Comment: @Fat-Zer, зачем набрасывать, когда есть yavta и v4l-utils? https://git.linuxtv.org/v4l-utils.git/tree/ & http://git.ideasonboard.org/yavta.git